# asNavFor not working in vue-slick slider

Tags: vuejs2, slick.js

I want to show the image in slick slider asNaVFor. Here is screenshot that I need.
[image]
On selecting image from the 2nd slick slider it will show in the 1st slider. There is break-point after each image and current image is shown on slider-1. Also display arrows in 2nd slider but not in slider-1 as you are seeing in the screenshot.

```
<template>
    <app-card
    :fullBlock="true"
    >
        <div class="top-selling-widget">
            <slick :options="slickOptions" ref="slickSetting1">
                <div v-for="news in newsData" :key="news.id">
                    <div class="thumbnail mb-2">
                        <img :src="news.newsSrc" width="100%" height="300" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </slick>
      <slick :options="slickOptions2" ref="slickSetting2">
                <div v-for="news in newsData" :key="news.id">
                    <div class="thumbnail mb-2">
                        <img :src="news.newsSrc" width="150" height="50px" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </slick>
        </div>
    </app-card>
</template>

<script>
import Slick from "vue-slick";
export default {
  components: {
    Slick
  },
    computed: {
        slickOptions() {
            return {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: false,
                fade: true,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                asNavFor: this.$refs.slickSetting2,
                rtl: this.$store.getters.rtlLayout
            }
        },
        slickOptions2() {
            return {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                dots: false,
                autoplay: true,
                speed: 2000,
                infinite: true,
                cssEase: "linear",
                focusOnSelect: true,
                asNavFor: this.$refs.slickSetting1,
                rtl: this.$store.getters.rtlLayout,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                responsive: [
                     {
                            breakpoint: 1200,
                            settings: {
                                 slidesToShow: 3,
                                 slidesToScroll: 1,
                            }
                     },
                     {
                            breakpoint: 991,
                            settings: {
                                 slidesToShow: 4,
                                 slidesToScroll: 1,
                            }
                     }
                ]}
            }
        },
   data() {
      return {
        newsData: [
          {
             id: 1,
             newsSrc:"/static/img/gallery1.jpg",
             newsTitle: "#WorldPopulationDay: India Likely to Overtake China by 2022",
             newsContent: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
             likes: "1k",
             views: "3k",
             comments:"200"
          },
          {
             id: 2,
             newsSrc: "/static/img/gallery2.jpg",
             newsTitle: "Check status of Mumbai local, long-distance trains as rains continue",
             newsContent: "when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries",
             likes: "2k",
             views: "5k",
             comments: "600"
          },
          {
             id: 3,
             newsSrc: "/static/img/gallery3.jpg",
             newsTitle: "Croatia lowest ranked team in history to reach World Cup final",
             newsContent: "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, ",
             likes: "500",
             views: "1k",
             comments: "300"
          },
          {
             id: 4,
             newsSrc: "/static/img/gallery4.jpg",
             newsTitle: "Telecom Commission approves net neutrality, new telecom policy",
             newsContent: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old",
             likes: "4k",
             views: "8k",
             comments: "1k"
          },
          {
             id: 5,
             newsSrc: "/static/img/gallery5.jpg",
             newsTitle: "Vistara orders Boeing, Airbus jets worth $3.1 billion",
             newsContent: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
             likes: "100",
             views: "500",
             comments: "50"
          }
        ]
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ref add class.

Pls follow this

```
Slick ref="slick_video" class="slider-for" :options="slickOptionsVideoInfra"

Slick ref="slick_infra" class="slider-nav" :options="slickOptionsInfra"


slickOptionsInfra: {
   asNavFor: ".slider-for",
},

slickOptionsVideoInfra: {
   asNavFor: ".slider-nav",
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Not use `ref=""` can't you use id for it

```
slickOptions: {
           arrows:true,
           slidesToScroll: 1,
           fade:true,
           asNavFor: '#slick1'
           
        },
```

Comment: Try improving your answer ... it is totally ununderstandable.